# How do you find out what the function $g(f(2))$ and $f(g(2))$ is?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm trying to find what the *g*$(f(2))$  and the *f* $(g(2))$ is.

Here are the functions for *f* and *g*:

Let *A* - $\{$1, 2, 3, 4$\}$ and *B* - $\{$a, b, c, d$\}$

- Let *f* : *A* $\rightarrow$ B be defined so that *f* - $\{$$\lt$1, b$\gt$,$\lt$2, c$\gt$, $\lt$3, d$\gt$, $\lt$4, a$\gt$$\}$
- Let *g* : *B* $\rightarrow$ A be defined so that *g* - $\{$$\lt$a, 1$\gt$,$\lt$b, 2$\gt$, $\lt$c, 4$\gt$, $\lt$d, 4$\gt$$\}$

This is what I've done so far, but i'm not sure if it's done correctly, please feel free to correct me.

$g(f(2))$ - We have $f(2)$ in *g* which is $f(2) = c$ and $g(c)$ which is $g(c) = 4$.

Is this done correctly or I'm I missing something out on this?

I'm not sure how i can solve the *f* $(g(2))$ would appreciate some help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You did g(f(2)) correctly. You can't do f(g(2)) because g(2) isn't defined (2 isn't in the domain of g)

Comment: ah great! thought I was doing it wrong. Alright yeah, that's what i was struggling with. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'll just add that as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did $g(f(2))$ correctly. You can't do $f(g(2))$ because $g(2)$ isn't defined since $2$ isn't in the domain of $g$.